# Exclusions for Jacoco plugin omitted in code coverage calculations

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I execute men clean verify to scan my. code coverage. When I add exclusions for Jacoco the result remains the same. I tried to put in various places in code below, with most logical option for me after /limits and before /rule, but with no effect at all:

```
         <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>70%</minimum>
                            </limit>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>70%</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
```

If I put exclusions after /rule and before /rules then I get info that the exclusions cannot be interpreted in the place they are, so I guess the placement is ok? I am putting the whole path to the classes:
src/main/java/com/../../Contact.java
I use Jacoco 0.8.8, mvn 3.9.2.